# Make window screenshot use transparent background

Tags: macos, monterey, screen-capture

Pressing <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> then pressing <kbd>space</kbd> then clicking on a floating window takes a screenshot of that floating window with the dropshadow included.

For some reason, mine now have white backgrounds...

How can I make it use a transparent background instead?

```
% defaults read com.apple.screencapture
{
    "last-analytics-stamp" = "699383078.004545";
    "last-messagetrace-stamp" = "607952564.008211";
    "last-selection" =     {
        Height = 597;
        Width = 1138;
        X = 336;
        Y = 220;
    };
    "last-selection-display" = 0;
    location = "~/Downloads";
    "location-last" = "~/Downloads";
    "show-thumbnail" = 0;
    showsCursor = 1;
    style = selection;
    target = file;
    video = 1;
}
```

Comment: What format are you saving the screenshots as?

Comment: @benwiggy PNG. I don't see any way to change it anyway (in cmd-shift-5 options)

Comment: It can be changed, and some formats don't allow transparency. So it's not that. Can you add the results of this Terminal command to your question: `defaults read com.apple.screencapture` Also what Mac model is this?

Comment: @benwiggy there's nothing in `defaults read com.apple.screencapture` that seems to be about background color. Macbook pro 2015. Until recently, these screenshots had always had transparent background.

Answer (score 2):

type in terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture type png
```

This rewrites the value of the key `type` from the default `jpg` to `png`. To revert just do the above command but replace with `jpg` instead.